# Resurrecting REALLY Old Questions

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Occasionally I see a new answer pop up on a REALLY old question (like 8+ years). I have done this a couple times myself, but mostly on accident when I didn't realize how old it was. I mostly try to avoid it because it just feels...weird. But I have also seen some old questions that I feel like I could contribute something to.

My gut tells me that there is absolutely nothing inherently wrong with doing this and my discomfort is entirely self imposed. But before I "get over it" and go digging around for old questions to answer, I want some clarification on what, exactly, the general consensus on this is.

**A.** It is highly encouraged, but underused
**B.** It is good thing, but not all that important
**C.** Nobody really cares
**D.** It is acceptable, but only occasionally
**E.** It is to be used with discretion, only if there is a really good reason for it (and what a good reason might be)

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know that if you've got something to say that no one else has said yet, answering extremely late should be fine, since future readers will be able to receive your knowledge, even if OP might not. I would refrain from restating what others have said, but if you've got something new to add to the post, by all means, I'd rather have a late answer than no answer.

Answer (score 20):

There are badges that you can only get by answering or editing old questions. It is definitely encouraged, by design.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you've got something useful to add, say it. There are plenty of people who will leap on it if they feel it inappropriate.